# Firefox WebExtension match content script on xhr call

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've never tried to create WebExtensions before. I'm trying to create a Helper for one web-site. I map content script on the appropriate page, but the web-site use only asynchronous calls to navigate between pages. In ff's console I see that all calls are marked as xhr. So my script is invoked only on reloading the particular page manually, but not while navigating.

Is it possible to map xhr calls and content scripts?
Should I use a kind of interceptor to do so? Is there a best practice to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I came out with is to extend the content script's visibility in manifest to the whole web-site and to check constantly path in the script:

```
var enabledPages = [
    "/page1",
    "/page2"
];
setInterval(function() {
    if(enabledPages.indexOf(window.location.pathname) > -1){
        // logic
    }
}, 1000);
```